# Best practices to write reusable rules

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I am specifically working on Drools. But, generally, I would like to know what are the best practices to write rules thar are "reusable" with any rules engine.

Answer (score 0):

Writing reusable business rules is a lot like writing reusable code in any language:

- Rules should have a single responsibility. (i.e. don't calculate four
  different values in a single rule, seperate them out)
- Abstract commonly used rules out into their own rule package so that
  can be shared with other rule models. (don't duplicate logic in
  multiple rules)
- Model rules at the appropriate level of abstraction.  The objects manipulated in your business rules should mirror the concepts familiar to the business users.